# Fill array with placeholders Javascript [IE supported]

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I have an array which I get from response of google Analytics.

My array looks like this:

```
var mobileYesterday = [
 {hour: "00", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
 {hour: "06", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
 {hour: "07", date: "20171208", pageviews: "5"},
 {hour: "08", date: "20171208", pageviews: "7"},
 {hour: "09", date: "20171208", pageviews: "4"}
];
```

Since a day exists out of 24 hours I would like to be able fill the array with placeholders, which will contain the date of today, the hour which isn't specified in the previous array and pageviews = 0. The array should also be ordered by hour, so that the array will look like this:

```
 var mobileYesterday = [
     {hour: "00", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
     {hour: "01", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "02", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "03", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "04", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "05", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "06", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
     {hour: "07", date: "20171208", pageviews: "5"},
     {hour: "08", date: "20171208", pageviews: "7"},
     {hour: "09", date: "20171208", pageviews: "4"},
     {hour: "10", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "11", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "12", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"},
     {hour: "13", date: "20171208", pageviews: "0"}
     etc..
];
```

I've tried to loop through the array with a for loop

```
var array = [];
    var date = moment().format("YYYYMMDD");

    var hourPlaceholder;
    for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        if(i < 10){
            hourPlaceholder = '0'+i;
        }
        if(i > 9){
            hourPlaceholder = i;
        }


       for (var k = 0; k < mobileYesterday.length; k++){
           if(!mobileYesterday[k].uur == hourPlaceholder){
              var array_record = [
                  { "hour": hourPlaceholder, "date": date, "pageviews":0}
              ]
               array.push(array_record);
           }else{
               array.push(mobileYesterday[k]);
           }
       }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

But this just returns the most weirdest array ever:

```
[[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],[{"hour":"00","date":"20171207","pageviews":0}],{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"},{"hour":"01","date":"20171207","pageviews":"1"},{"hour":"07","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"08","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"09","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"10","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"11","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"12","date":"20171207","pageviews":"9"},{"hour":"13","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"14","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"15","date":"20171207","pageviews":"6"},{"hour":"16","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"17","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"18","date":"20171207","pageviews":"4"},{"hour":"19","date":"20171207","pageviews":"7"},{"hour":"20","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"21","date":"20171207","pageviews":"8"},{"hour":"22","date":"20171207","pageviews":"5"},{"hour":"23","date":"20171207","pageviews":"3"}]
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Oops. I've place'd the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a simplified approach for the formatted `hour` and omit `moment`, because you could take the date from the given array.

The take an index for the given array and just check against with `hour`.

```js
function fillArray(data) {
    var array = [],
        hour,
        i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        hour = ('0' + i).slice(-2);
        array.push(data[j] && data[j].hour === hour
            ? data[j++]
            : { hour: hour, date: data[0].date, pageviews: 0 }
        );
    }
    return array;
}

var mobileYesterday = [{ hour: "00", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1" }, { hour: "06", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1" }, { hour: "07", date: "20171208", pageviews: "5" }, { hour: "08", date: "20171208", pageviews: "7" }, { hour: "09", date: "20171208", pageviews: "4" }];

console.log(fillArray(mobileYesterday));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure of your array, mobileYesterday.indexOf(10) will return **-1** always.

Also, `mobileYesterday[k].uur`  will always be `undefined`, since there is no property called `uur` in your object.

Use `Array` *constructor* along with `map`

```
var pad2 = ( int ) => ( "0" + int ).slice( -2 ); 
var output = Array(24).join("0").split("").map( function(it, in){
  in = pad2(in);
  var doesExists = mobileYesterday.find( s => s.hour == in ); //find existing object
  if( !!doesExists )
  {
     return doesExists;
  } 
  else
  {
     return { hour : in, date : "20171208", pageviews : 0 }; //if object doesn't exists return a new one
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var mobileYesterday = [
 {hour: "00", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
 {hour: "06", date: "20171208", pageviews: "1"},
 {hour: "07", date: "20171208", pageviews: "5"},
 {hour: "08", date: "20171208", pageviews: "7"},
 {hour: "09", date: "20171208", pageviews: "4"}
];

var pad2 = (int) => ("0" + int).slice(-2);
var output = Array(24).join("0").split("").map(function(it, ind ) { 
  ind = pad2( ind );
  var doesExists = mobileYesterday.find(s => s.hour == ind );
  if (!!doesExists) {
    return doesExists;
  } else {
    return {
      hour: ind ,
      date: "20171208",
      pageviews: 0
    }; //if object doesn't exists return a new one
  }
});
console.log( output );
```